# Zurb Foundation + Owl Carousel -> IOS devices Crash

Tags: javascript, ios, css, zurb-foundation

We use owl carousel for responsive swipe elements containing 1 or 2 elements depending on display size. This is embedded in a site using Foundation 5. When opening the page or swiping (depending on device version) the page crashes. Any idea, what it could be. Not that we don't use the Foundation Grid here to wrap our Element, so no floats etc.

```
<section class="banderole-row">
<div class="banderole--carousel_wrapper">
    <div class="owl-carousel banderole--carousel">
        #foreach($banderoleEntry in $m.local.banderoleEntryListMobile)
            <div class="banderole--carousel__mini item">                        
                <a href="$banderoleEntry.linkTarget"><img src="$banderoleEntry.mobileImageVariant"/></a>  
                <p>#@linkOrSpan($banderoleEntry.linkTarget)$banderoleEntry.title#end</p>
            </div>
         #end
     </div>
 </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: Have you checked the console log for errors? Can you provide the JS you're using?